# Problem with the use of C++ in an Unreal Engine project

Tags: unreal-engine5

I wanted to create a project that uses C++ but it says that it could not be compiled, this is the message:

```
The project could not be compiled. Would you like to open it in Visual Studio 2022?

Running C:/Program Files/UE_5.3/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Build.bat Development Win64 -Project="E:/files/Unreal Projects/MyProject5/MyProject5.uproject" -TargetType=Editor -Progress -NoEngineChanges -NoHotReloadFromIDE
Using bundled DotNet SDK version: 6.0.302
Running UnrealBuildTool: dotnet "..\..\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool\UnrealBuildTool.dll" Development Win64 -Project="E:/files/Unreal Projects/MyProject5/MyProject5.uproject" -TargetType=Editor -Progress -NoEngineChanges -NoHotReloadFromIDE
Log file: C:\Users\pietr\AppData\Local\UnrealBuildTool\Log.txt
Creating makefile for MyProject5Editor (no existing makefile)
@progress push 5%
Parsing headers for MyProject5Editor
  Running Internal UnrealHeaderTool "E:\files\Unreal Projects\MyProject5\MyProject5.uproject" "E:\files\Unreal Projects\MyProject5\Intermediate\Build\Win64\MyProject5Editor\Development\MyProject5Editor.uhtmanifest" -WarningsAsErrors -installed
Total of 0 written
Reflection code generated for MyProject5Editor in 1.49836 seconds
@progress pop
Building MyProject5Editor...
Using Visual Studio 2022 14.39.33522 toolchain (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519) and Windows 10.0.18362.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10).
Determining max actions to execute in parallel (4 physical cores, 8 logical cores)
  Executing up to 4 processes, one per physical core
  Requested 1.5 GB memory per action, 2.99 GB available: limiting max parallel actions to 1
------ Building 6 action(s) started ------
[1/6] Compile [x64] SharedPCH.Engine.Cpp20.cpp
C:\Program Files\UE_5.3\Engine\Source\predefined C++ types (compiler internal)(420): error C2248: 'FHazardPointerCollection::FHazardRecord::FHazardRecord': impossibile accedere a private membro dichiarato nella classe 'FHazardPointerCollection::FHazardRecord'
C:\Program Files\UE_5.3\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Experimental\Containers\HazardPointer.h(86): note: vedere la dichiarazione di 'FHazardPointerCollection::FHazardRecord::FHazardRecord'
C:\Program Files\UE_5.3\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Experimental\Containers\HazardPointer.h(77): note: vedere la dichiarazione di 'FHazardPointerCollection::FHazardRecord'
C:\Program Files\UE_5.3\Engine\Source\predefined C++ types (compiler internal)(420): note: il contesto di creazione dell'istanza del modello (prima il meno recente) ?
C:\Program Files\UE_5.3\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Experimental\Containers\HazardPointer.h(133): note: vedere il riferimento all'istanza 'void __builtin_array_init_helper<FHazardPointerCollection::FHazardRecord>(_T *,size_t) noexcept(<expr>)' della funzione modello di cui ? in corso la compilazione
        with
        [
            _T=FHazardPointerCollection::FHazardRecord
        ]
[2/6] Resource Default.rc2
Total time in Parallel executor: 16.25 seconds
Total execution time: 20.99 seconds
```

I have tried also to create a blueprint project and then add the C++ scripts but once I try adding that it won't work. What am I doing wrong? I'm using UE5.3

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind i solved it out, the problem was that i had to download this in VS: MSVC v143 - VS 2022 C++ x64/x86, for everybody in future who endded up like this i'll reccomand you to check if u have installed this, for what i have undertood this thing is automaticaly downloaded but it has write at the end (latest version) some people suggest to deleat it and put the version we want.